# parameters contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditMusicRecording

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditMusicRecording(int Id)
{
    return View(_musicService.GetMusicRecording(Id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditMusicRecording(Music_Recording recording)
{
    try
    {
        _musicService.EditMusicRecording(recording);
        return RedirectToAction("Recordings");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Music", action = "Categories", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If EditMusicRecording don't pass id parameter throw this error.

This code is causing the error.

```
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("EditMusicRecording", new { Id = 5 });
```